# How to solve Facebook's Bad URL Timestamp error while attempting to open an image URL?

Tags: url, timestamp

Hi I'm opening the following URL:

https://scontent.flhe2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/123495201_3416334628447348_2428850074136092273_o.jpg?_nc_cat=107&ccb=2&_nc_sid=7206a8&_nc_eui2=AeHk9MUHe1PTFqDnBsbFZuvannJsJDg-qpWecmwkOD6qlUzAzyNTH1UtE63oU2V8AaZ8CscuHcFnyAYN0bvjIEbO&_nc_ohc=MWUVsUeltWoAX8R3j9u&_nc_ht=scontent.flhe2-1.fna&tp=6&oh=d557b11a263bc53f804abeefcf41b12a&oe=5FC4BEFE

But it's giving me Bad URL TimeStamp error.

How to resolve this issue? TIA!

Answer (score 8):

It only appears to give the error if you do not copy the whole URL. In your question only the part up to the first ampersand (&ccb) is highlighting as a URL, that's all that's included if you click on it. If you copy and paste the whole thing, it works for me.

I was just looking into this problem for videos, and anyone else that is looking for an answer to this: replace any instance of  & amp ; with just & and make sure there are no escape characters (e.g. change \ \ / to just /) and it worked for me.

Comment: Can you please show the correct version of url. I do not understand what one has to replace with &cmp?